# Regex to read fixed width numeric fields

Tags: regex

I would like regex(es) that can parse right-justified numeric values in a fixed length field with optional leading whitespace. (This is essentially FORTRAN output but there are many other tools that do this). I know the width of the field.

Assume the field is an integer of width 5 (`I5`). Then the following are all conformant numeric values:

```
"  123"
"12345"
"-1234"
"   -1"
```

I can make no assumption about the previous and following fields. Thus the following is valid for `I3,I5,I2`:

```
"-121234512"
```

and yields the values `-12, 12345` and `12`.

There should be no additional code associated with the regex. I am using Java regex but I would like this to be fairly general (at least conformant with C#).

If this can be done for integers, I would also like the regex(es) for real numbers which include a decimal point, e.g. `F10.3`

```
"   -12.123"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex:

```
(?=[ ]*-?\d+)[ -\d]{5}
```

matches all of your examples:

```
"  123"
"12345"
"-1234"
"   -1"
```

And chaining them in groups:

```
((?=[ ]*-?\d+)[ -\d]{3})((?=[ ]*-?\d+)[ -\d]{5})((?=[ ]*-?\d+)[ -\d]{2})
```

on the input:

```
-121234512
```

matches:

```
$1 = -12
$2 = 12345
$3 = 12
```

A short explanation:

```
(?=        # start positive look ahead
  [ ]*     #   zero or more space
  -?       #   an optional minus sign
  \d+      #   one or more digits
)          # end positive look ahead
[ -\d]{5}  # spaces, minus sign or digits, exactly 5 times
```

As you can see, the lookahead forces the order of the characters (spaces before digits and/or minus sign, minus sign before digits).

And a version for you float example might look like:

```
(?=[ ]*-?\d+(\.\d+)?)[ -\d.]{10}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex:

```
^(?= *-?[0-9]*$).{5}
```

[Rubular link](http://www.rubular.com/r/r0jIUYpZek)